# Empty "items" response when listing channels by category

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am unsuccessfully trying to list channels by categoryId via the following request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id%2Csnippet%2Cstatistics&categoryId=<CATEGORY_ID>&maxResults=50&fields=items(id%2Csnippet(thumbnails%2Fmedium%2Furl%2Ctitle)%2Cstatistics(subscriberCount%2CvideoCount%2CviewCount))%2CnextPageToken%2CpageInfo%2FtotalResults&key=<API_KEY>
```

Everytime the response is empty, i.e. "items" field is empty.

Comment: According to YouTube Data API v3 [Channels: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) documentation `categoryId` is deprecated.